# Why print release and debug message in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

```
build.gradle
```

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    println('release')
  }
  debug {
    println('debug')
  }
}
```

When I exec `./gradlew assembleDebug`, print message

```
release
debug
```

Why print release message? I not understand it.

I want to execute some code in release mode, but it also can be executed in debug mode, how can I do?

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            println('release')
            packagingOptions {
                println('release packaging options')
                exclude 'lib/armeabi/*.so'
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILDTIME", "\"${buildTime()}\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RELEASE", "true"
        }
        debug {
            println('debug')
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILDTIME", "\"${buildTime()}\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RELEASE", "false"
        }

    }
```

When I run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, print message

```
release
release packaging options
debug
```

How can I do ? I want not execute release statement in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why the messages are printed even though you didn't execute the any tasks, you need to understand the build phases of Gradle build lifecycle, i.e. **initialisation**, **configuration** and **execution**.

Most of the scripts will be run during **configuration** phase. The settings under file `settings.gradle` will be executed during **initialisation** phase. And the statements inside `doFirst{}` and `doLast{}` will be run during **execution** phase.

For your case

```
buildTypes {
  release {
     println('release')
  }
  debug {
     println('debug')
  }
}
```

Above code will actually be run during the project **configuration** phase and the message will be seen inside console.

> How can I do ? I want not execute release statement in debug mode.

When you run

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Even though you see the release message, it does not affect your debug output of your debug command.

See the official documents: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html .

Comment: `Even though you see the release message, it does not affect your debug output of your debug command.` But I've already exec this command, It's sure run release packaging options in debug mode, my result is not what I want.

Comment: `packagingOptions` is a global option regardless to build type. if you want to have different packaging options for the `.so` files for debug and release, you can configure it using `jniLibs.srcDirs`.

Comment: You can refer to my answer to your other question regarding how to arrange your JNI libs.

Answer (score 1):

The messages are printed because the `println` statements are executed during **task declaration / initialization** stage. That does NOT mean that the tasks are **executed**.

Comment: The code is executed in release and debug statements.

Comment: yes, for gradle it's a normal behavior: the DSL closures are evaluated and executed along with the code in them. You could add `println 'AAAAA'` into any block and it will print 'AAAAA' out.

Comment: I want to execute some code in release mode, but it also can be executed in debug mode, how can I do?

Comment: usually you define a gradle task for that, perhaps with dependencies on other tasks. what code do you want to execute?

Comment: ```packagingOptions {
                println('release packaging options')
                exclude 'lib/armeabi/*.so'
            }```, exec above code.

Comment: the thing is `buildTypes` is not supposed to execute any code. It only prepares some configuration for other tasks to rely on. From what I can see you configuration i.e. `packagingOptions { exclude 'lib/armeabi/*.so' }` should be fine